# When should square brackets be used in Python function return statement?

Tags: python, return

I am new to Python and do not understand when square brackets need to be included around a return variable. For example, I have often seen the below format used, where `[seed]` has the square brackets.

```
def seed(self, seed=None):
    self.np_random, seed = seeding.np_random(seed)
    return [seed]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given code will return a list. If you are not returning an list and simply how the seed variable is, you would have simply written - `return seed`. In your example, you seem to be returning a seed wrapped as a list from the function. So  you have to use `return [seed]`.

So,

- `return seed` - Returns seed from the function as it is
- `return [seed]` - Returns seed from the function by wrapping it in a list. So the value seed will become an element of the newly formed list.

Answer (score 1):

You should use square brackets only when you want to return a list.

`return seed` returns the seed, `return [seed]` returns a list with `seed` as the only element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a single value, you can use `return seed`
Or if you want multiple values to be returned, you can use `return [seed]`

**Note:**
Basically, `[]` refers to a list of items. you can pass multiple items separated by commas in the list like `[1, 7, 6, 'seed']`. This will help you to return multiple values at once.